# How to turn auto detect off for extensionless files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: image where it autodetects ini file]

How to turn this auto detect for files having no extensions and when there is low certainty, it should be plaintext by default.

Files with high certainty are those who have the `#!` in starting, so we can detect which language it is, but for other files i don't want that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the `workbench.editor.languageDetection` setting, which can be toggled globally or on per-language basis.

The [1.60 release of Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_automatic-language-detection) made some changes to the language detection, including:

> This release we are enabling automatic language detection by default and also expanding detection to include files that don't have a file extension.

> ...power users who use untitled text editors as a scratch pad, no longer need to explicitly set the the language mode, which we hope will streamline their workflow.