# Run button left

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[screen with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azb6q.jpg)

I lost button **Run Code** in VSC with Python. Where can I search and turn on this button?

Search in internet and vsc settings

Comment: By "left", you mean "gone"? I thought you meant "left side" at first. BTW, "Search in internet and vsc settings" is a sentence fragment; is that what you already tried? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: Did you make any changes to VSC recently, like installing/uninstalling any extensions? Or did you change any debug settings?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your language mode is set to Python when you have a Python file open.  If you have it set to something else, that button will disappear.

For example, when I change my language mode to C#, it disappears.  Switching back to Python, it reappears:

[image: changing language mode removes button gif]

You can change the language mode via the command palette by doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search for "Change Language Mode".

What I suspect is you may have started a new file, and it's still set to "Plain Text" which is the default.  Visual Studio Code is [suppose to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111358/6530134) try and determine what language you are using automatically *if it can* (unless you have this setting disabled).